# Would this question be on-topic for this site?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I have this question:

Title: How can I access the fm radio chip in my Android smartphone.

Content: Android is based on a Linux Kernel, and is therefore a variant of Unix. As such I would expect some sort of command console/command prompt to be accessible. According to [this site](http://freeradioonmyphone.org/take-action/) and [this site](http://www.npr.org/sections/alltechconsidered/2015/04/16/400178385/the-hidden-fm-radio-inside-your-pocket-and-why-you-cant-use-it), most smartphones have a FM radio chip that is deactivated because phone carriers want us to pay for the moderate amounts of data it would require to stream music via services such as Pandora. I personally use up to 1/2 of my data for this purpose.

Rather than wait and hope something to change, I would like to go ahead and bypass this inconvenience. I have some level of hardware expertise, and I have rooted my phone, a [LG Optimus Fuel](http://www.lg.com/us/cell-phones/lg-L34C-optimus-fuel) serviced under tracfone. How would I go about activating my radio and how would I access it afterward?

Back to the meta question:

Would this be on topic for this site? I read through the help center here as well as on Unix SE, and nothing seemed to disqualify it from being on-topic from either, but I am not entirely sure it is on-topic. In a vague sense it involves both my power-using desires and Unix (Android is descended from Unix and they have an [android](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/android) tag). I just wanted to be clear about this before I asked the question.

Comment: I suspect [android.se] would be the place for it.

Answer (score 5):

It's definitely off-topic here. But there is an [Android.SE](http://android.stackexchange.com) site that would happily take it.

Comment: Thanks. Just had to be sure before I asked ;)